# Keeping track of changes in a table

Tags: sql

My colleague at work has posed me a question which I cannot answer (due to a lot of inexperience) which is related to tracking changes of relevant fields on a table.

So imagine that we have 3 tables with 20 fields each. Let's consider for this example that each of these tables has 2 fields, one named LastUpdatedOn and another named LastUpdatedBy.

If we wanted to keep track of changes in these 3 tables but only for a couple of specific fields without creating an History table for each of them containing their last version before they were updated, how could we keep track of changes on these relevant fields and still keep it generic?

Comment: If you're not going to create a History table, exactly where would you expect to save your history?

Comment: This seems puzzling, at least to me it is. My colleague said we cannot use a History table to keep track of the changes. The thing here is, you don't need to know what the old values were, all you need to know is that an important field has been changed. That's the kind of tracking that's needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to create an History/Audit table for each of them. You can have a **single** table, which stores the table and field name for the fields you want to keep track of:

`audit(audit_id, table_name, field_name, action_flg, updated_by, updated_on, val_before, val_after, pk_value1, pk_value2, pk_value3, pk_value4, pk_value5)`.

You need to store the primary key (fields `pk_value1` to `pk_value5`) of the table in order to uniquely identify the row that has been changed. `action_flg` is used if you want to keep track of updates, insertions, or rows that have been deleted. Oracle uses this table structure in some of its products.

For instance, suppose you have a table `person(person_id, name, email)`, and you need to track changes made to the field `email`:

1. A new person (`id=1`) is created: `insert into audit(1, 'person', 'email', 'A' /* add */, 'USER', '11-03-2011', null, 'email@mail.com', 1, null, null, null, null);`
2. E-mail of person `1` is updated:
   `insert into audit(2, 'person', 'email', 'C' /* change */, 'USER', '12-03-2011', 'email@mail.com', 'new_email@mail.com', 1, null, null, null, null);`
3. Now suppose the e-mail of person `70` is updated:
   `insert into audit(3, 'person', 'email', 'C' , 'USER', '12-03-2011', 'p70email@mail.com', 'new_p70mail@mail.com', 70, null, null, null, null);`

Comment: This is one valid option, but like everything has it's negatives as well as positives. For one you can create a pretty nice hot spot if you have thousands of tables writing audits to one table for example.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to know what has changed, only that some important field has changed, then just add another timestamp column, `LastImportantUpdateOn` or something like that. Then add a trigger to catch edits to the fields considered "important" and write a new timestamp.

If you need to know which field changed, add a new timestamp for each field instead of one in general.