# Log changes to data in a table1 and insert the old and New value in Table2 without triggers

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server-2008

To start with I am not an SQL guy so wanted to achieve below functionality which might be very easy for an SQL guy to achieve.

Actually we want to trace the Log of each an every entry on a table in another History table with Column name for which data is updated and what was Old and New value for updated Column.

For eg if we update Column1 value of Table1 then in history table we have to insert Old and New value of Column1 and Column name itself (i.e. which column was updated and with what value).

Comment: I dont want to use triggers to achieve this......I have to do this without triggers. So when I call an update SP with parameters I have to check the data changes and for which column and accordingly update them in History table

Comment: I want to achive something simalar what is answered in below post but need to know how to get the old and new value and Column name http://stackoverflow.com/a/5274264/5524841

Comment: Check my answer, maybe It will help for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't like to use `TRIGGERS` you can use `OUTPUT` in following:

**UPDATED ANSWER**

You can store updated values in different columns, if value isn't updated you can pass `NULL`, something like:

**QUERY**

```
UPDATE #t1
SET FirstName = 'bar',
    LastName = 'foobar'
OUTPUT  INSERTED.Id, 
        DELETED.FirstName, 
        CASE WHEN INSERTED.FirstName = DELETED.FirstName THEN NULL ELSE INSERTED.FirstName END, 
        DELETED.LastName, 
        CASE WHEN INSERTED.LastName = DELETED.LastName THEN NULL ELSE INSERTED.LastName END, 
        DELETED.City, 
        CASE WHEN INSERTED.City = DELETED.City THEN NULL ELSE INSERTED.City END
INTO #t2 (Id, [First Name - Old], [First Name - New], [Last Name - Old], [Last Name - New], [City - Old], [City - New])
```

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
CREATE TABLE #t1
(
    Id INT,
    FirstName NVARCHAR(MAX),
    LastName NVARCHAR(MAX),
    City NVARCHAR(MAX)

)
CREATE TABLE #t2
(
    Id INT,
    [First Name - Old] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [First Name - New] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [Last Name - Old] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [Last Name - New] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [City - Old] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [City - New] NVARCHAR(MAX),
)
INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES (1, 'foo', 'foo2', 'foo3')
```

**OUTPUT FROM UPDATED TABLE**

```
Id  [First Name - Old]  [First Name - New]  [Last Name - Old]   [Last Name - New]   [City - Old]    [City - New]
1   foo                 bar                 foo2                foobar              foo3            NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for the Quick response, I want to achieve the same thing but the Output should also include the name of the Column for which data was updated. Also it wont work for multiple column updates

Comment: thanks a lot, this is a good example for what I am trying to achieve. I will work further on your example to Get the Column name as well in OutPut and will try to make it generic for all tables so each updated old and new value will be in 2 different rows.